# JavaFX Error: Incompatible types: ContentDisplay cannot be converted to VPos

Tags: javafx

I use a `GridPane` as layout for `Main`, but when I add a `Button` like in my code... Show this type of Error..

```
Incompatible types: ContentDisplay cannot be converted to VPos
```

My controller  and 
Main class

```
public class Main extends Application 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
    {

        GridPane grid =new GridPane();

        grid.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
        Button b1=new Button();
        grid.setGridLinesVisible(true);
        grid.setConstraints(new Button("Check"),3,4,1,2,LEFT,CENTER,Priority.SOMETIMES,Priority.SOMETIMES);
        grid.add(new Button ("like"), 2, 4);
        Scene scene =new Scene(grid);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share more details (FXML + Controller)

Comment: Please Help me@oszd93

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've added a static import for `ContentDisplay.CENTER`. Therefore it's used in this line:

```
grid.setConstraints(new Button("Check"),3,4,1,2,LEFT,CENTER,Priority.SOMETIMES,Priority.SOMETIMES);
```

However this method expects `VPos`, which is not assignable from `ContentDisplay`, which is why this doesn't compile.

You could simply fix this import by changing the class you import from, but I do not recommend using static imports, since it makes the code harder to read (You have to check the imports to know where the member comes from).

I recommend importing `HPos` and `VPos` and using this code instead.

Furthermore `setColumnConstraints` is a `static` method and should not be referenced using an variable. (It's not wrong, but it's bad practice.) Being a `static` method this does not add the `Button` as child of `grid`. You need to do this in addition to setting the constraints.

```
Button button = new Button("Check");
GridPane.setConstraints(button,
                        3, 4,
                        1, 2,
                        HPos.LEFT, VPos.CENTER,
                        Priority.SOMETIMES, Priority.SOMETIMES);

grid.getChildren().add(button);
```

Comment: Thanks for your Help@fabian